# Facebook PAGE Comments are dissapearing on my page at intervals of 15minutes to few hours

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

Facebook PAGE Comments are dissapearing on my page at intervals of 15minutes to few hours.

**What I require:**
Tentative fix, link to fixes for the issue provided below on 2 videos and screenshots.

**First Video for context:**

https://www.loom.com/share/cef6bdc93d9d4976b2df4ef2694ec0dd

**Second Video for context:**
https://www.loom.com/share/b1ee879a3ed247e78ddc43f6a37c4784

Meta Business Suite says X number of Comments are available in a particular post:
e.g:

**Facebook Post:** https://www.facebook.com/sastodeal/photos/a.523159294390829/8655916951114982/
[image]

**Meta Business Suite Analytics:**
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Community Bot,
We've added in videos to better explain context on the same: 

First Video for context:

https://www.loom.com/share/cef6bdc93d9d4976b2df4ef2694ec0dd

Second Video for context: https://www.loom.com/share/b1ee879a3ed247e78ddc43f6a37c4784